# How to add google cloud print in phonegap for hybrid android app?

Tags: android, cordova, printing, google-cloud-print

I am developing a hybrid app for android using phonegap. I am in need of adding print functionality to print the html content. After making many google search I found that we can use google cloud print api in our applications. Is there any example for adding cloud print api in phonegap app.
Thanks in advance.